# Export a key value table to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I currently have a key/value table in my rails application and I am trying to export all the rows in a `key => value` array format when I ask for the JSON format.

The closest I can get is

```
{
    navigationBarColor: "#E31937"
},
{
    navigationBarImage: "Background-NavBar"
},
```

But I would only like to get an array of key/value pair, not an object for each. I was looking for something like

```
"navigationBarColor":"#E31937",
"navigationBarImage":"Background-NavBar",
```

My table only has a key and a value column, both in varchar.

Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

**Update:** My serializable_hash looks like this now:

```
def serializable_hash()
    {key => value}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `:reduce` via `:merge`.

```
> rows = [{ navigationBarColor: "#E31937" }, { navigationBarImage: "Background-NavBar" }]
=> [{:navigationBarColor=>"#E31937"}, {:navigationBarImage=>"Background-NavBar"}]

> rows.reduce(&:merge!)
=> {:navigationBarColor=>"#E31937", :navigationBarImage=>"Background-NavBar"}

> puts rows.reduce(&:merge!).to_json
{"navigationBarColor":"#E31937","navigationBarImage":"Background-NavBar"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I replaced my serializable_hash with `{key => value}.reduce(&:merge!).to_json` and now I am getting something like this: http://pastebin.com/iwg4hmVa It is very close, I am probably missing something small here

Comment: My example works if you change your `:serializable_hash` back to the previous implementation and then merge/reduce that array of single-element hashes.  You can also try `your_result_set.map{ |el| { el.key => el.value } }.reduce(&:merge!).to_json`.